# pyqt5 can not close a topmost fullscreen qdialog on mac osx

Tags: pyqt, fullscreen, pyqt5, qdialog, topmost

I am writing an app that can take a screenshot on osx 10.9.5 using pyqt5; code sample is like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore,Qt
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication

class CScreenshot(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CScreenshot,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)  #1

    def screenshot(self):
        #grab screen and paint into this dialog
        #so user can modify the pix through this dialog
        _screen = Qt.QApplication.primaryScreen()
        self.m_snapPix = _screen.grabWindow(0)
        #...
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.exec_()

    def drawLine(_p1,_p2):
        pass
    #...

class CMainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CMainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.m_btnScreenshot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.m_btnScreenshot.clicked.connect(self.onBtnClk)

    def onBtnClk(self):
        ss = CScreenshot()
        ss.screenshot()     #here into the CScreenshot's message loop
        #process next step balabala...


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CMainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here comes the question: When I click the button, the fullscreen dialog pops up and stays on topmost, everything works fine. But when I press the `Esc` button, the dialog should close and show the main window, but the screen just fixed by a black fullscreen window, which has the title python. If I remove the `#1` marked line, it will work fine, but I need the dialog to stay topmost, hope someone can help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Though on Linux.

Comment: Yes,it's working fine on Windows and Linux.So the whole cross-platform thing is just an illusion,right?

Comment: In our project we've only seen the problem with `close()` not closing a fullscreen window on MacOS machines, there doesn't seem to be any problems on other machines. We are running PyQt 5.9 btw

Answer (score 0):

I read the doc,and found the answer:"To return from full-screen mode,call showNormal()".It's my stupid.

Comment: Okay, this solves the problem for our project as well, but it's still strange that we have to call showNormal for MacOS right? The documentation has information on returning from fullscreen but doesn't say anything about a problem with closing on MacOS, so it seems like this may be a bug in Qt/PyQt correct? (We're running PyQt 5.9 btw)